# Profile detailed GPU Memory Usage

Tags: memory, gpu, profiler, direct3d

So I have a GPU memory leak in certain scenarios in my application. However, I am not aware of any detailed memory profiler for the GPU like those for the CPU. Are there anything out there that can achieve this? I am using D3D (since its WPF, there are d3d9, d3d10, d3d11 components...)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using VS2013 then you can run graphics debug on applications that use D3D. I'm not sure if it's available for WPF applications, though.

Comment: But that's only for D3D11 (ReportLiveObjects or something like that) I believe. SInce i am using WPF, which required d3d9, I need a more general solution if possible (or a combination).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the debug setting in Dx control panel? This helps you dump the id of the leaking allocation. You can then proceed to set a HKLM registry value and break on the leaking allocation, as is explained here:

http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/direct3d-programming-tip-5-use-the-debug-runtime/

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/313718-tracking-down-a-directx-leak/

You can also try NSight, which you can download for free from NVidia. For Maximus cards there is also a specific GPU Debugger, and otherwise you can use the Graphics Debugger and try to isolate the memory bump there. In the Performance Debugger you can detect both OpenGl and DirectX events, though this is more performance oriented.

Comment: I tried Nsight, but it doesn't play well with WPF unfortunately :( I'll take a look at the HKLM registry proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your GPU's vendor (As you have not provided us with the information), here are the possible solutions:

Intel: Use the Intel Media SDK 's GPU Utilization Utility. This comes packaed in the Intel INDE (Integrated Developer Environment).

AMD: CodeXL provides an on-the-fly debugger and an extensive memory profiling tool, and is now provided as part of their GPUOPen initiative.

NVIDIA: Use the Nvidia Visual Profiler (NVVP) combined with traces from Nvidia Nsight, and these utilities are provided with the standard Nvidia CUDA installer.

Notes:

1. With Nvidia, you must also install the provided GPU driver (~from the CUDA SDK) to enable any form of GPU-based driver profiling and debugging. Take note of the above limitation if you use your development rig for other purposes such as gaming, as the bundled driver is often much, much older than the stock, Game-ready drivers.

Thanks and regards,

Brainiarc7.